# Implode integers into mysql select statement (Result is repeating)

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-clause, implode

I want to implode integers and echo them as a comma separated string. I have been an this for almost three hours and I can't get it to work.
The output I am currently getting is:

> 104104,105104,105,106

instead of:

> 104,105,106

I checked the php forums and it says to use `mysql_fetch_assoc` to avoid this but it doesn't work. If anyone has any ideas please help. My PHP looks like this:

```
<?PHP

$user_name = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "testdb";
$server = "127.0.0.1";

$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

if ($db_found) 
{
$SQL = "SELECT TableA.c1 FROM TableA ";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
     while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
     { 
     $itinarry[]= $db_field['c1'];
     $string = implode(',',$itinarry);
     echo $string;
     }
mysql_close($db_handle);

}
else  
{
    echo "Database NOT Found ";
    mysql_close($db_handle);        
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: try this `while($db_field = mysql_fetch_assos($result)) { $itinarry[] = array_values($db_field);  } $string = implode(',',$itinarry);`. Place implode outside your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it's doing is

`echo implode(",", array(104))`

`echo implode(",", array(104, 105))`

`echo implode(",", array(104, 105, 106))`

Which results in:

`104104,105104,105,106`

Put

```
 $string = implode(',',$itinarry);
 echo $string;
```

out side out the `while` loop;

Comment: .This Explanation was what i needed.i took it out of the loop and it worked perfectly.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to this:

```
while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
 { 
 $itinarry[]= $db_field['c1'];
 }
 $string = implode(',',$itinarry);
echo $string;
```

Comment: Thank you this code worked perfect exactly what i was looking for.i took the statement :  $string = implode(',',$itinarry);
 out of the loop.